# How to Implement this UI with CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress, web

I'm working on Wordpress template, and got this little problem which is:
I can't position the date label above the image thumbnail, as you can see here:

http://cl.ly/image/3X1j3h3j0E0X

If I make it *position: absolute* its position would be changed while the windows is changing.

How could I implement the right CSS for that.

This is the CodePen example, try to resize the window:

```
`http://codepen.io/msabdullah/pen/rplgC`
```

Comment: use `position:relative` for parent element. like this. http://jsbin.com/pecudayisuvi/1/edit

Comment: Do not use tricks to "workaround" the quality filters. They're here for a reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a combination of `position: relative` and `left` `right` `top` `bottom` to position it correctly.  It should be positioned relative to the parent element.

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
<div>
```

If you had the above html structure then you would need to make sure both had positioning, and then position the child relative to the parent:

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  position: relative:
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

This is just an example, but it should be something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give `position relative` to parent element to maintain the uniformity.
check the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/pecudayisuvi/1/edit)**.

CSS like this: Where div is parent element have `position:relative`.

```
img, p{display:inline-block;}
div{position:relative;}
p{position:absolute; right:0; top:0;}
```